# Word for “place of power”

Tags: single-word-requests, literature

I’m looking for a word (or literary/biblical reference) that means “a high place close to power and/or god.”

As in “the stage was her ___, where she felt as if she could conquer the world.”

Right now I’ve settled on “dominion,” but that doesn’t quite capture the spatial connotation I’m after. “High ground” is better on that front but lacks the immense power connotation I need.

I swear I’ve got one on the tip of my tongue, but I just can’t quite reach it.

Comment: How about "Mount Olympus"? or "Celestial Sphere"? "Divine abode"?

Comment: her Nirvana, sounds like to me. dominion is a very "masculine" word, associated with nasty, colonial regimes and dictatorships. It is also Biblical. Do you want to haul all that baggage? Less la-dee-dah: crow's nest

Comment: @Lambie nirvana is, by definition, a state of non-being, and therefore powerlessness. A useful concept for someone who loses herself on a stage, but not likely a place from which she might feel as if she could conquer the world.

Comment: Nirvana can be paradise, for some. her paradise found.

Comment: @Lambie The lion has no power over the lamb in paradise, if ever there were such creatures there.

Comment: a state of perfect happiness; an ideal or idyllic place.
plural noun: nirvanas
"Hollywood's dearest dream of small-town nirvana" [Oxford Dictionary via Google] [sigh]

Comment: @Lambie, that's just not what the question is asking for, even if it is a related experience one might have in place that they enjoy. Appreciate it though!

Comment: You know what? You come here and ask for suggestions to stem your creative writing miseries and then you tell me something does not mean something when it does. Crow's nest or quarterdecks are places from which the world was conquered.

Comment: @Lambie, that's funny — I actually *directly* compare the stage to a quarterdeck a bit later!

Comment: Are you looking for **realm**?

Comment: Actually, one often sees the exact phrase "place of power" used for this.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul probably not? I feel that realm does impart a sense of ownership, but not necessarily the idea that this is where the power is derived from? Not sure if that impulse is just me.

Comment: @GEdgar why can't English be more like German and give me one, elegant, extremely long word for the precise connotation I seek 

Comment: @PatrickPerini If there was a really good one in German, English would have "borrowed" it by now and changed the spelling and pronunciation to cover its tracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Cathedral***

> The stage was her **cathedral**, where she felt as if she could conquer the world.

Used literally, a [cathedral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cathedral) is where the Bishop's throne (or cathedra) is located. Used figuratively, it can be an important location of authority or power, with connotations of religious contemplation or being closer to the divine.

> To Susan, an art gallery was her cathedral, her sacristy, her confessional, and her life’s work. ([Source](https://patconroy.com/pat-conroy-for-gourmet-magazine/))

Comment: I also like cathedra!

Comment: @PatrickPerini I worked it in there on purpose, because I like it too, but I wasn't sure if that would be too obscure for your audience :)

Comment: If the word is too obscure for the audience, your context clues aren't strong enough. That's what I always say!  (Cathedral is probably the better choice.)

Comment: I like reading things that make me want to look up a word to make sure I understand exactly what it means - not everyone keeps a dictionary at hand when reading though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bastion suggestive of power

Also stronghold

Or zenith

Bailiwick

Answer (score 0):

"*Powerhouse*" could render what you are looking for.

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/powerhouse))
> country, organization, or person with a lot of influence, power, or energy:
> ♦ Germany is an economic powerhouse.
> ♦ The university is no longer the academic powerhouse that it once was.
> ♦ She's a powerhouse of original ideas and solutions.

- The stage was her powerhouse, where she felt as if she could conquer the world.

([ref;](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_Perfect_Moment/SJsQ2WbvFMoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22her+powerhouse%22&dq=%22her+powerhouse%22&printsec=frontcover))  At home , in the kitchen that was her powerhouse , centre of strategic planning and theatre of operations , Yvonne Kelly was having a fit of stove rage.

Comment: @Cascabel I believe this means that the stage is the place from which emanates influence, power, etc., and that she could draw from those, derive power for herself. Isn't that the mind of the OP's text? Of course, I think that you have to take "the stage" figuratively.

Comment: @Cascabel I added a specifc example to the answer.

Comment: I've *never* seen this used in this way, and stylistically (purely subjective) I'm not in love with it, but it's both fascinating and an obviously correct choice! Thank you!

Comment: I just don't think it works that way.  In all the Cambridge examples, *powerhouse* is used as a generative source i.e., a powerhouse is a prodigious producer.  With the stage example maybe she could be a powerhouse on stage.

Comment: @Jim A generative source, in this case, generate something for someone's benefit. If, on top of that, it is _your_ generative source, obviously, you benefit from it.

Comment: @Jim this is more in line with the contexts with which I'm familiar, but the reference quote ("the kitchen that was her powerhouse") is exactly the structure I'm looking. Agreed that it seems atypical, though.

Comment: Well an engine generates power

Answer (score 0):

I immediately thought of "genius loci" but I don't think that applies here so much? Locus (of control/power) might work in the same vein, but I am not so sure the more I think on it. I agree with the use of dominion and domain in any case, maybe a similar word like turf or zone could be used instead.

Comment: Hi, Fahad, and welcome. This isn't a typical discussion board - our goal is to provide established usages, preferably with citations (where applicable). Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and see if you can [improve this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do like "genius loci" as a suggestion though. I wouldn't have thought of it!